Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154
I have a simple PowerShell script as below
$excel = new-object -ComObject excel.application
$filePath = 'filename.xlsm'
$wb = $excel.workbooks.open($filePath)
$excel.Run('Macro')
$excel.quit()
Stop-Process -Name "Excel"
When I trigger the script either in SSIS package or through Task Scheduler, it works as expected. But when I deploy the SSIS package in SSMS and trigger the script as SQL Server agent job, I get the error as "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))..".
I made sure I have Excel installed and also entries exist for both InProcServer and LocalServer with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} in Registry Editor. I also registered the dll in InProcHandler32 which is ole32.dll using regsvr32.exe. I also tried replacing the powerShell script with python using win32com library. But getting the error "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid Class string', None, None). We want to migrate the jobs in Task Scheduler to SQL Server agent.
I am not sure why my log shows CLSID as {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, when I am trying to open excel with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}. I am not sure even if they are related. Can anyone help me troubleshoot the error.

It may be an x64 vs x86 issue, ie: the client runs as x86 but Excel runs as x64 or the reverse.

Thank you! I had set the "Run64bitruntime" property to False in Visual Studio and also in Sql server agent job, in Advanced configuration tab, set the "32bitRuntime" to yes. Still getting same error

I can't test SSIS but REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG is usually because the calling client doesn't see the required CLSID in the registry it reads (32 or 64bit version depending on calling client process bitness). The fact is the null guid (all 0s) here is quite unusual. You also might want to check security aspects (like identity of the calling COM client vs identity of COM server, etc.). And last you can use procmon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon to see what keys are accesses, errors, etc. (filter by registry access and possibly calling process)

Excel.Application should be callable by either 32-bit or 64-bit COM because it is a local server and registers to run both ways. My big question would be whether calling it from SQL server, somehow, somewhere, CoInitialize() is not being called? IDK. It is a weird situation for sure.
